# seekbar played time and remaining time showing large integer value.?

Tags: android

In m using android seekbar with play and remaining time for the following sample code for songprgress handler with thread. whenever i clicked next/previous song, it showing large integer value. How to solve this issue?

```
class SongProgressUpdateThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {

        if (mp != null) {
            int currentPosition = 0;
            int total = mp.getDuration();
            while (currentPosition < total && mp.isPlaying() && stopSongProgressThread==false ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
                songProgress.setProgress(currentPosition);
                showProgress(currentPosition, total);
            }

        }
    }
}





private void showProgress(int currentPosition, int duration) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("playedTime", getPlayedTime(currentPosition));
    bundle.putString("remainingTime",getRemainigTime(currentPosition, duration));
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.setData(bundle);
    songProgresshandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

Handler songProgresshandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        final Bundle b = message.getData();
        playedTime.setText(b.getString("playedTime"));
        remainingTime.setText("-" + b.getString("remainingTime"));
    }
};
```

Comment: Please paste your getPlayedTime() and getRemainingTime implementation

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Please update the question with the requested code. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use VideoView and MediaController to do it.
Such as:

```
VideoView vv = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setMediaPlayer(vv);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
vv.setMediaController(mediaController);
vv.start();
mediaController.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

what did you do when click Next/Previous button
maybe the mediaPlayer is under a invalid status, watch the LogCat any Error message in it?(like "getDuration() in invalid stauts")